# Wordpress Gallery shortcode: Display one category ID only

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Good Day. I am using a Gallery shortcode in my wordpress site to display images. 
Problem is that I wasnt the gallery to show only images from a certain category, for example category id 35. How do I specify it in the shortcode?

Shortcode:

```
 [custom_gallery style="1" source="**cat=%cat_id%**" link="image" description="0" size="200x200" limit="10"]
```

Now I have tried the following, but does not work -

```
cat=%35%
cat=%cat_id=35%
```

The shortcode code (because it is a custom shortcode):

```
/**
 * Gallery posts shortcode
 */

function gallery_posts_func($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "limit" => '5',
        "cat" => '',
        "thumb_width" => '',
        "thumb_height" => '',
    ), $atts));
    global $wp_query,$paged,$post;
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();

    $query .= '&posts_per_page='.$limit;
    $query .= '&post_type=gallery';
    $query .= '&taxonomy=gallery_cat';
    $query .= '&gallery_cat='.$cat;

    $wp_query->query($query);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="gallery-holder fourthcol shortcode">
<?php

                $gogo_gallery_video_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_video_url', true);
                $gogo_gallery_links_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_links_to', true);
                $gogo_gallery_title_links_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_title_links_to', true);
                $gogo_gallery_custom_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_custom_link', true);

                if ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_video_url && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_image") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_video_url.'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_image") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.$thumbnail[0].'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_content") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_link") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_custom_link.'">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title) {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</h5>';

                } else {
                echo '';
                }
        ?>  
<div class="gallery-box">
    <div class="gallery-image prettygallery">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <?php
                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');

                if ($gogo_gallery_video_url && $gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_image") { 
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_video_url.'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_image") {
                echo '<a href="'.$thumbnail[0].'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo '<img   src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_content") {
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_link") {
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_custom_link.'">';
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } else {
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                }
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php if ($gogo_gallery_short_desc) { ?><em><?php echo $gogo_gallery_short_desc; ?></em><?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>


    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode("gallery_posts", "gallery_posts_func");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are probably:

```
cat="35"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer- - But does not work. It shows: Custom gallery: no attached images, or only one attached image…Eben though I have images under that category ID...Can't I use  category name or slug perhaps(even though the option does not appear in the shortcode

Comment: See the shortcode code which I added to the post just now. Maybe you could make out something there. I will see what I can change there

Comment: thanks mate. It actually works, I referenced the wrong cat. Appreciate your help